# show my result in a selected div

Tags: php, jquery

I have this form:

```
<FORM id="frmVote" action="../vote_dir/proccess.php" method="post">
     <table id="tblMain" align="center">
        <tr>
        <td class="header"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <?php
            include "../vote_dir/loadpoll.php";
             ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <input id="votefor" name="votefor" type="hidden"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="button">
             <INPUT class="btnVote" onclick="return confirmSubmit()" type="submit" value="vote"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="footer"></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</FORM>
```

and this is part of the proccess.php:

```
<?php
  $votefor = $_POST["votefor"];

  //Get the IP of the user
  $domain = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
  $today = date("m/d/Y");

  echo "<table id=\"tblResults\" align=\"center\">";

  //MORE CODE

// Generate the results table
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load("../vote_dir/xml/results.xml");
  $pollitems = $doc->getElementsByTagName("pollitem");
  foreach( $pollitems as $pollitem )
  {
    $entries = $pollitem->getElementsByTagName("entryname");
    $entry = $entries->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $votes = $pollitem->getElementsByTagName("votes");
    $vote = $votes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $tempWidth = $vote / $maxvotes;
    $tempWidth = 300 * $tempWidth;
    $votepct = round(($vote / $maxvotes) * 100);
    echo "<tr><td width=\"45%\" class=\"polls\">$entry</td>";
    echo "<td width=\"35%\" class=\"resultbar\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"background-color: ";
        getRandomColor();
        echo "; width: $tempWidth px;\">$votepct%</div></td><td class=\"each_vote\" width=\"20%\">($vote votes)</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "<tr><td width=\"45%\" class=\"total\" colspan=\"3\">Σύνολο ψήφων: $maxvotes</td>";
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Like it is now it works fine. but I am trying to make it load my results in a specific div instead of opening the results like

I am trying to use this jquery (that I used in other things), it is working partialy since it opens the results in the div but it seems it doesn't sent the form into the proccess.php since I can see the result page without any change or message e.g "You have already voted".

```
  .delegate('.btnVote', 'click', function(){
     var keyValues = {
      votefor : $(this).parent().find('input[name="votefor"]').val()
     };
     $.post('../vote_dir/proccess.php', keyValues, function(rsp){
      $('#voting').load('../vote_dir/results.php');
     });
     return false;
  })
```

this is my loadpoll.php

```
<?php 
  // Load the results xml file
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load("../vote_dir/xml/results.xml");
  $root = $doc->getElementsByTagName("results")->item(0);
  $question = $root->getAttribute("question");
  echo "<table id=\"tblPoll\" align=\"center\"><tr><td class=\"question\">$question</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td class=\"pollitem\">";
  $pollitems = $doc->getElementsByTagName("pollitem");
  $id = 1;
  // Loop through each item, and create a radio button for each item
  foreach( $pollitems as $pollitem )
  {
    $entries = $pollitem->getElementsByTagName("entryname");
    $entry = $entries->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $votes = $pollitem->getElementsByTagName("votes");
    $vote = $votes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    if ($id==1)
        echo "<input id=\"entry$id\" class=\"radiobutton\" onclick=\"setVote('$entry')\" type=\"radio\" name=\"poll\" value=\"$entry\">$entry<br>";
    else
        echo "<input id=\"entry$id\" onclick=\"setVote('$entry')\" type=\"radio\" name=\"poll\" value=\"$entry\">$entry<br>";
    $id = $id + 1;
  }
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $('.btnVote').live('click', function () {
                $.post('../vote_dir/savevote.php', { votefor: $.trim($(this).parents('form').find('input[name="votefor"]').val()) }, function (data) {
                    $('#voting').html(data);

                    //Or

                    //$('#voting').load('../vote_dir/results.php');
                });

                return false;
            });
```

Comment: in loadpoll.php it will contain attribute id '#voting'. i did not see any attribute id="#voting" and what output savevote.php will return?

Comment: it seems to work but immediately after it shows the correct data it reloads the result.php (which then gets the default messages... e.g instead of displaying "you already voted" it says "voting results are")

Comment: where u r checking the condition for "you already voted" in savevote.php  post (use if else condition). so that if he is already voted echo  "you already voted"; else echo "voting result";

Comment: I am using else statements... problem seems to be that results.php loads 2ice. If I just call results.php I will get the voting result but without any formation (like plain text). So with your script for a millisecond I get the result.php as it should be and then it loads again resulting in the plain text formation and default msgs.

Comment: after post success $('#voting').load('../vote_dir/results.php');  remove this line and use  $('#voting').html(data); as above code

Comment: okkk... Now I feel stupid. I was wondering what that OR was there for. Ok now I am getting the correct msgs but inside the proccess.php where I say MORE CODE has some formation for the result table which are not displayed. (I am getting them if I do as I say at the beginning: without try to make it open in a specific div)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11585/discussion-between-pavlos1316-and-thulasiram)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
$(this).parent().find('input[name="votefor"]').val()
```

to

```
$('#votefor').val()
```

I think the "$(this).parent()" leads to the `<td>`

Comment: Hmm... or it should be `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input[name=votefor]').val()`... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = $(this).parent().find('input[name= votefor]').val();
```

or

```
$data = $(this).parent().find('input[name= votefor]').val();
```